# How can you wrap a JUnit 5 Test

Tags: junit, junit5

In JUnit 4 you could use a Rule to wrap a test so that you could execute code both before and after a test had run. In most cases this could be accomplished with an @Before and @After method or an ExternalResource rule. However some control flow constructs (like try-with-resources) cannot be split into two methods. In most cases, there are alternatives to these constructs which allow you to split them into two methods. For example, with try-with-resources, you can manually acquire and close a resource instead of using a try block.

The specific problem that I have run into is that the database library I use, jOOQ, only has transaction methods that take a callback. (See https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) You cannot call something like:

```
context.startTransaction()
doStuff()
context.commit() // Or rollback()
```

In JUnit4 this is ok because you can write a rule like so (in Kotlin, but the equivalent works in Java):

```
class TransactionRule(private val dbSessionManager: DBSessionManager) : TestRule {
    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            override fun evaluate() {
                dbSessionManager.transaction {
                    base.evaluate()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything similar in JUnit 5?

Comment: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks should help.

Comment: Or use s/t like this JPA extension offers: https://github.com/dadrus/jpa-unit

Answer (score 4):

You can write an [InvocationInterceptor](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-intercepting-invocations) in place of the JUnit4 rule:

```
public class TransactionInvocationInterceptor implements InvocationInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void interceptTestMethod(Invocation<Void> invocation,
            ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method> invocationContext,
            ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Throwable {
        runInTransaction(() -> {
            try {
                invocation.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new RuntimeException(t);
            }
        });
    }
}

@ExtendWith(TransactionInvocationInterceptor.class)
class InvocationInterceptorTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        …
    }
}
```

One difference is that `interceptTestMethod` only wraps the test method, not other lifecycle methods such as `beforeEach`. It's possible to intercept the other lifecycle methods individually with the other methods in `InvocationInterceptor`, but not multiple at a time (for example, if you want to call both `beforeEach` and the test method in one transaction).

Comment: I'm surprised that JUnit guide doesn't mention it. InvocationInterceptor is still an experimental feature, which may be crucial fact to at least some of you. What it does mean exactly:


`EXPERIMENTAL - Intended for new, experimental features where we are looking for feedback.Use this element with caution; it might be promoted to MAINTAINED or STABLE in the future, but might also be removed without prior notice, even in a patch.`

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs. Thanks for that suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can't use the [JUnit 5 test lifecycle callbacks](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks) as they would require you to follow the `doStuff` route with `context` calls `Before`/`After` that you indicate won't work.

Would using JUnit 5 [Dynamic Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests) instead work?

This provides for test factories consisting of collections of dynamic test with a name and an executable (lambda). You could then do something like this:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest.dynamicTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;

@TestFactory
Collection<DynamicTest> transactionTestCollection() {
    return Arrays.asList(
        dbTest("1st dynamic test", () -> assertTrue(true)),
        dbTest("2nd dynamic test", () -> assertEquals(4, 2 * 2))
    );
}

private DynamicTest dbTest(String name, Executable tst) {
    return dynamicTest(name, () -> dbSessionManager.transaction(tst));
}
```

Comment: In theory yes, but unfortunately that ends up being almost as much boiler plate as wrapping every test individually since you have to add each test to the return collection yourself. Admittedly, I haven't tried it yet, but I'm assuming it doesn't play nicely with IntelliJ either since you presumably can't easily run individual tests.