# Using JUnit 5 (Jupiter), how do i intercept all method calls?

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

Goal:
Intercept all test methods.
If an exception is thrown by the test, call `e.printStackTrace()` then rethrow the exception.

I'm not sure how to register the interceptor for all test methods.

Sample Interceptor:

```
public class PrintTraceInterceptor implements InvocationInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void interceptTestMethod(Invocation<Void> invocation,
            ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method> invocationContext,
            ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Throwable {

        AtomicReference<Throwable> throwable = new AtomicReference<>();

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            try {
                invocation.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throwable.set(t);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Throwable t = throwable.get();
        if (t != null) {
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

###### Update w/ clarification:

I'm able to intercept a specific test class's methods by adding `@ExtendWith(PrintTraceInterceptor.class)` to the class definition, but I'd like to globally register it for all test methods in all classes.

Comment: [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167184/how-can-you-wrap-a-junit-5-test)

Comment: @Eugene That gets me one class intercepted, but not all classes (unless I manually add to each class). I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: there is a way to register a global extension in junit5, google and search for that

Comment: The only way I've found so far requires messing with command arguments for maven to enable the ServiceLoader which I don't have access to do.

Comment: wait, [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-engines-custom) would not work for you?

Comment: To enable service loader, you need to specify a command argument for it to work. Since I don't have access to update the command, it wouldn't work for me unless there's a way to add it after-the-fact.

Comment: I'll give it a shot anyway. maybe I'll get lucking and it's enabled by default, now.

Comment: look at the provided answer, it explains what `i was trying to tell you

Answer (score 0):

According to [this instruction](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic) in order register a global extension (without modifying the run command) you simply need to add two files to your classpath:

1. Extension configuraion file where you declare your extension fully qualified name
   `src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension`:

```
com.example.PrintTraceInterceptor
```

2. Junit Platform configuration file, where you enable autodetection so that the extension configuration is taken into account

`src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties`:

```
junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true
```

Now `mvn test` command applies your extension to any test class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.